# Illegal access exception in createAgent() Jade

Tags: java, agents-jade

I've got exception when i try to create agents in my simple program.
There are my code:
  DefaultAgent.java:

```
package ru.spbu.mas;
import jade.core.Agent;
import jade.core.behaviours.TickerBehaviour;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class DefaultAgent extends Agent {
 DefaultAgent() {
        super();
   }
@Override
    protected void setup() {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(getAID().getLocalName());
        System.out.println("Agent #" + id);
        addBehaviour(new TickerBehaviour(this, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)) {
            @Override
            protected void onTick() {
                    stop();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainController.java (i hidded some imports. Think problem not in them):

```
    class MainController {
        private static final int numberOfAgents = 5;
        private AgentController[] agents = new AgentController[numberOfAgents];
        private int steps = 10;
        void initAgents() {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.instance();
            Profile p = new ProfileImpl();
            p.setParameter(Profile.MAIN_HOST, "localhost");
            p.setParameter(Profile.MAIN_PORT, "10098");
            p.setParameter(Profile.GUI, "true");
            ContainerController cc = rt.createMainContainer(p);
            try {
                for(int i = 1; i <= MainController.numberOfAgents; i++) {
                    //Exception in that string of code
                    AgentController agent = cc.createNewAgent(Integer.toString(i), "ru.spbu.mas.DefaultAgent", null);
                    agents[i - 1] = agent;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        void startAgents() {
            try {
                for(int i = 1; i <= MainController.numberOfAgents; i++) {
                    agents[i].start();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Here my project hierarchy:
[project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqFRn.png)

Here my Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation files('C:\\Users\\chote\\Desktop\\JADE-bin-4.5.0\\jade\\lib\\jade.jar')
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
}
```

Here App.java:

```
package ru.spbu.mas;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainController mc = new MainController();
        mc.initAgents();
        mc.startAgents();
    }
}
```

Here exception's traceback:

```
jade.core.IMTPException: Illegal access exception in createAgent() - Caused by:  Class jade.core.management.AgentManagementService$CommandTargetSink can not access a member of class ru.spbu.mas.DefaultAgent with modifiers ""
    at jade.core.management.AgentManagementService$CommandTargetSink.createAgent(AgentManagementService.java:630)
    at jade.core.management.AgentManagementService$CommandTargetSink.handleRequestCreate(AgentManagementService.java:533)
    at jade.core.management.AgentManagementService$CommandTargetSink.consume(AgentManagementService.java:488)
    at jade.core.CommandProcessor$SinksFilter.accept(CommandProcessor.java:253)
    at jade.core.Filter.filter(Filter.java:89)
    at jade.core.Filter.filter(Filter.java:90)
    at jade.core.Filter.filter(Filter.java:90)
    at jade.core.CommandProcessor.processIncoming(CommandProcessor.java:229)
    at jade.core.BaseNode.serveVerticalCommand(BaseNode.java:163)
    at jade.core.BaseNode.serveHorizontalCommand(BaseNode.java:111)
    at jade.imtp.leap.NodeLEAP.accept(NodeLEAP.java:60)
    at jade.core.management.AgentManagementProxy.createAgent(AgentManagementProxy.java:67)
    at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl$1.createAgent(AgentContainerImpl.java:176)
    at jade.wrapper.ContainerController.createNewAgent(ContainerController.java:135)
    at ru.spbu.mas.MainController.initAgents(MainController.java:36)
    at ru.spbu.mas.App.main(App.java:6)
Nested Exception:
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class jade.core.management.AgentManagementService$CommandTargetSink can not access a member of class ru.spbu.mas.DefaultAgent with modifiers ""
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436)
    at jade.core.management.AgentManagementService$CommandTargetSink.createAgent(AgentManagementService.java:612)
    at jade.core.management.AgentManagementService$CommandTargetSink.handleRequestCreate(AgentManagementService.java:533)
    at jade.core.management.AgentManagementService$CommandTargetSink.consume(AgentManagementService.java:488)
    at jade.core.CommandProcessor$SinksFilter.accept(CommandProcessor.java:253)
    at jade.core.Filter.filter(Filter.java:89)
    at jade.core.Filter.filter(Filter.java:90)
    at jade.core.Filter.filter(Filter.java:90)
    at jade.core.CommandProcessor.processIncoming(CommandProcessor.java:229)
    at jade.core.BaseNode.serveVerticalCommand(BaseNode.java:163)
    at jade.core.BaseNode.serveHorizontalCommand(BaseNode.java:111)
    at jade.imtp.leap.NodeLEAP.accept(NodeLEAP.java:60)
    at jade.core.management.AgentManagementProxy.createAgent(AgentManagementProxy.java:67)
    at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl$1.createAgent(AgentContainerImpl.java:176)
    at jade.wrapper.ContainerController.createNewAgent(ContainerController.java:135)
    at ru.spbu.mas.MainController.initAgents(MainController.java:36)
    at ru.spbu.mas.App.main(App.java:6)
jade.wrapper.StaleProxyException: Illegal access exception in createAgent() - Caused by:  Class jade.core.management.AgentManagementService$CommandTargetSink can not access a member of class ru.spbu.mas.DefaultAgent with modifiers ""
    at jade.wrapper.ContainerController.createNewAgent(ContainerController.java:140)
    at ru.spbu.mas.MainController.initAgents(MainController.java:36)
    at ru.spbu.mas.App.main(App.java:6)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ru.spbu.mas.MainController.startAgents(MainController.java:47)
    at ru.spbu.mas.App.main(App.java:7)
```

Why I've got that this exception if DefaultAgent hasn't additional fields. All modifiers are private. What mean modifier ""? How can I fix it? True version of program are much bigger. Above program gotted by commented a large bit of code.

Comment: I don't have access to Jade Source Code, can you provide the code from "(AgentManagementService.java:612)"?

Comment: @Augunrik When i clicked i was adressed by Idea to this place in decompiled class:
This code was calling double times:
[link](https://imgur.com/CZxbVjK)
[link](https://imgur.com/QjT32Vh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you make the constructor of your DefaultAgent public.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it solution. I dont got more this exception! Later I'll try run full program.